# In Grails, How can I create a domain model to link two of another model?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm currently trying to create a Friendship domain object to link two User objects (with a bit of additional data: createDate, confirmedStatus). My domain model looks as follows

```
class Friendship {

User userOne
User userTwo
Boolean confirmed
Date createDate
Date lastModifiedDate

static belongsTo = [userOne:User , userTwo:User]

static constraints = {
userOne()
userTwo()
confirmed()
createDate()
lastModifiedDate()
}
}
```

I've also added the following entries to the user class

```
static hasMany = [ friendships:Friendship ]
static mappedBy = [ friendships:'userOne' , friendships:'userTwo' ]
```

When I do this, the result is a new friendship created (and viewable through the controller) with both users listed in their respective places. When I view the details of userOne, I see the friedship listed. When I view the details of userTwo, no friendship is listed. This is not the behavior I expected. What am I doing incorrectly? Why can't I see the friendship listed under both users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared the `userOne` and `userTwo` properties twice in the `Friendship` class. Once here:

```
static belongsTo = [userOne:User , userTwo:User]
```

And again here:

```
User userOne
User userTwo
```

Change your Friendship class to this

```
class Friendship {

  Boolean confirmed
  Date createDate
  Date lastModifiedDate

  static belongsTo = [userOne:User , userTwo:User]

  static constraints = {
    userOne()
    userTwo()
    confirmed()
    createDate()
    lastModifiedDate()
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference, the friendship is still only seen as a property of one of the friends.